# How did the atmospheres of Soyuz, Shuttle, Mir, and ISS compare?

Tags: iss, space-shuttle, soyuz-spacecraft, mir

Soyuz and the Space Shuttle each docked with Mir and the International Space Station.  When docked, the crew vehicle and station each share a common atmosphere for the crew to breathe.  However, **how did the atmospheres of these spacecraft compare** (pressure, gas composition) **when normally operated as individual spacecraft?**

Related:

- [Space shuttle cabin atmosphere system](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38030/26446)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All these craft were designed to maintain the rough equivalent of a sea level atmosphere.

[image]

Reference: [Life Support Concepts for Space Travel](http://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/supplement/102202_LifeSupportPart1.pdf)

Shuttle Environmental Control and Life Support System Mission Control Center screenshot from STS-88

[image]

Reference: Personal notes

[image]

Reference: [Fundamentals of Aerospace Medicine](https://books.google.com/books?id=_6hymYAgC6MC&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=mir%20cabin%20atmosphere%20oxygen&source=bl&ots=Ny7dTWHBQx&sig=ACfU3U2CHkh_bBnu9aOV0Bp6EiGlORGHwg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2_ses8dboAhVFXawKHTkyD7sQ6AEwC3oECAoQLg#v=onepage&q=mir%20cabin%20atmosphere%20oxygen&f=false)

> The Soyuz space ship uses an atmosphere of 21 % oxygen and 79 %
>   nitrogen at a pressure of 1 bar, just like the ISS.

Reference: [Emergency decompression of a Soyuz space ship and decompression sickness?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28366/6944)

Comment: I really like that plot from *Life Support Concepts for Space Travel*. I can guess why some of those lines are important, but I'm wondering if there are specific concerns about the max N2 partial pressure and max O2 % inclined lines. I'm guessing that the O2 *partial pressure* is the main one that determines how well the lungs can oxygenate the blood, but does max O2 % have to do with combustion safety? Any idea why the max N2 partial pressure line at 11.6 psi is significant? Are these best asked as a new question?

Comment: There is definitely a flammability concern at high O2 levels, and a new question would be great.